# how to set separate ICON to the separate exe

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, executable

I want to **set a separate icon** to **separate executable builds** with **multiple configuration build**.

My application contains multiple build configuration, I used **MSBuild** to build multiple exes.

But problem is that I cannot set different icons for the exes as per build configuration.

I already tried to set the icon using build events but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution for this. click on project properties.
Build Event->Pre-Build Event

Add following line

copy /Y "res\App icon\WiFi-32x32.ico" "res\Final Green icon.ico"

In Command Line

and for next configuration 
Add Following Line.

copy /Y "res\App icon\AW-32x32.ico" "res\Final Green icon.ico"

In Command Line

Add this code for all configuration just need to change icon file.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The .rc file is pre-processed first.  So you can simply use #if to conditionally define icons, just like you can in a C++ source file.  Right-click the .rc file, Open With, choose the text editor.  Locate the line that declares the icon:

```
 IDI_WIN32PROJECT1      ICON         "Win32Project1.ico"
 IDI_SMALL              ICON         "Small.ico"
```

And replace it with

```
 #include "mainicon.rc2"
```

And create mainicon.rc2, it ought to resemble something like:

```
 #ifdef DEBUG
 IDI_WIN32PROJECT1      ICON         "Debug.ico"
 IDI_SMALL              ICON         "Debug_small.ico"
 #else
 IDI_WIN32PROJECT1      ICON         "Release.ico"
 IDI_SMALL              ICON         "Release_small.ico"
 #endif
```

Then project + Properties, Resources, General, add "DEBUG" to the Preprocessor Definitions setting for the Debug configuration.  The seemingly odd extra step of adding the .rc2 file is there to avoid the resource editor from getting confused.

Comment: Thanks for solution, I already tried it and it worked when building single configuration. but when i trying to build all configuration at a time (because i need to build 8 configuration) using batch build then its not working.

Comment: That's a PEBKAC problem, don't expect a lot of help from "it doesn't work".